# Is there a package of decorators for __init__ that would make it copy args into object's fields without explicit assignment?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

[pinject](https://github.com/google/pinject#auto-copying-args-to-fields) these awesome decorators: `@copy_args_to_internal_fields` and `@copy_args_to_public_fields`. They do exactly what they say on the tin, and are *exactly* what I'm looking for.

Is there a standalone package somewhere (I can't seem to find it on Google) that do precisely this? Needless to say, I don't want to add the whole of `pinject` as a dependency. A bit of an overkill. I'm after speedy editing and saving me typing!

EDIT: removed license requirement; pinject's Apache license is fine so I guess I could just copy their implementation.

Comment: Why not just copy over the [`initializers` module](https://github.com/google/pinject/blob/master/pinject/initializers.py) then? The `pinject` project did the same to the [`decorator` package](https://github.com/google/pinject/blob/master/pinject/third_party/decorator.py).

Comment: And what is the exact problem with the Apache license anyway?

Comment: Thanks Martijn — you've challenged my assumptions.

I wasn't sure about what licenses I could use or not; thus I post a question like this on SO ;) so that I can get feedback on whether I'm being an idiot or not. In actual fact, my project already _DOES_ use some Apache-licensed libraries already. It looks looks very permissive for my purposes and I really could just make use of it. I'll accept your answer when I get it working with my code!

Comment: The other thing is... copying into fields seems so common.
"_surely_ that exists already"

Answer (score 2):

Translating the `pinject.initializers` module  to a standalone version:

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps


def copy_args_to_internal_fields(fn):
    """Copies the initializer args to internal member fields.

    This is a decorator that applies to __init__.
    """
    return _copy_args_to_fields(fn, 'copy_args_to_internal_fields', '_')


def copy_args_to_public_fields(fn):
    """Copies the initializer args to public member fields.

    This is a decorator that applies to __init__.
    """
    return _copy_args_to_fields(fn, 'copy_args_to_public_fields', '')


def _copy_args_to_fields(fn, decorator_name, field_prefix):
    if fn.__name__ != '__init__':
        raise ValueError('@{0} cannot be applied to non-initializer {1}.{2}'.format(
            decorator_name, inspect.getmodule(fn).__name__, fn.__name__))

    arg_names, varargs, unused_keywords, unused_defaults = (
        inspect.getargspec(fn))

    if varargs is not None:
        raise ValueError('decorator @{0} cannot be applied to {1}.{2} with *{3}'.format(
            decorator_name, inspect.getmodule(fn).__name__, fn.__name__, varargs))

    @wraps(fn)
    def CopyThenCall(self, *pargs, **kwargs):
        for index, parg in enumerate(pargs, start=1):
            setattr(self, field_prefix + arg_names[index], parg)
        for kwarg, kwvalue in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, field_prefix + kwarg, kwvalue)
        fn(self, *pargs, **kwargs)

    return CopyThenCall
```

This does without the [`decorator` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) dependency as well.

Demo:

```
>>> from standalone_initializers import *
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @copy_args_to_public_fields
...     def __init__(self, foo, bar=None, baz=1):
...         print vars(self)
... 
>>> Foo(1, 2)
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
<__main__.Foo object at 0x106bb2e90>
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @copy_args_to_internal_fields
...     def __init__(self, foo, bar=None, baz=1):
...         print vars(self)
... 
>>> Foo(1, 2)
{'_foo': 1, '_bar': 2}
<__main__.Foo object at 0x106bb2f50>
```

Comment: Btw, if this is just the code from `pinject` then it's still covered by their license, regardless of someone reposting it. Even if posting it for discussion on SO can be considered "fair use" (or equivalent in your jurisdiction) not subject to license, it does not follow that all uses of the code by anyone who sees it on SO are also "fair use" not subject to license. Neither does SO's cc-by-sa license overrule the original Apache license (unless Martijn Pieters is the copyright holder in `pinject`, in which case by posting part of it here he's just relicensed that part).

Comment: The code functionality here is minimal and the same or similar functionality has been posted here on SO before.  I can rewrite this from scratch if you like, but the result would look pretty much the same.

Comment: I doesn't bother me whether you rewrite or not :-) If the questioner has a serious reason for wanting to avoid the project's licensing, though, then copy-pasting 30-ish lines of source should not be acceptable regardless of how simple it is to reproduce the functionality in 30-ish lines of your own. Unless, of course, `pinject` themselves ripped those lines off someone else, in which case they can't claim copyright or the right to restrict its use. All that said, copyright law is complex and ultimately comes down to what your lawyer thinks you can get away with...

Comment: My point really is just that the questioner can't hope to "launder" open source code out of its license by asking someone to re-post it verbatim on SO :-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys! @SteveJessop, it turns out that Apache was fine for my purposes even though I specified it in the question (well, I'm not a lawyer, sorry!), though apparently that constraint has made for some quite interesting discussion surrounding fair use.
Your points are valid, but I think I'll just go on right ahead to use a portion of pinject's code =]